# Uncaught Reference Error: okButtonElementFirebase. All about addEventListener

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

having a hard time on addEventlistner. it gives me uncaught reference error when page is loaded

```
    window.onload= initializer;
    var refUsers;
    var tableBody;
```

INITIALIZER

```
    function initializer(){
refUsers=firebase.database().ref().child("users");
tableBody = document.getElementById("table_body");
loadTables();
```

}

LOADS TABLE

```
    function loadTables(){
refUsers.on("value", function(snap){
    var data = snap.val();
    var file11 = "";
    for(var key in data){
            file11 += "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + data[key].firstname + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data[key].lastname + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data[key].birthdate + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data[key].email + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data[key].date + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + data[key].time + "</td>" +
                            '<td>' +
                                '<button class="btn btn-sm btnColorAccept center-block okButton" dataOk-confirmation="' + key + '">' +
                                    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>' +
                                'ACCEPT</button>' +
                            '</td>' +
                            '<td>' +
                                '<button class="btn btn-sm btnColorDecline center-block removeButton" dataRemove-confirmation="' + key + '">' +
                                    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>' +
                                'DECLINE</button>' +
                            '</td>' +
                      "</tr>;";
    }
    tableBody.innerHTML = file11;
    if(file11 != ""){
        var elementForOkButton = document.getElementsByClassName("okButton");
        for( var i=0; i< elementForOkButton.length; i++){
            elementForOkButton[i].addEventListener("click", okButtonElementFirebase, false);
        }
    }
});
     }                //end table function
```

GOT ERROR ON THIS LINE

elementForOkButton[i].addEventListener("click", okButtonElementFirebase, false);

FOR BUTTON WHEN CLICKED

```
      function okButtonELementFirebase(){
var keyOkButton = this.getAttribute("dataOk-confirmation");
var firebaseRefUsers = refUsers.child(keyOkButton);
firebaseRefUsers.remove();
     }
```

Comment: FIREEBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. ReferenceError: okButtonElementFirebase is not defined

Uncaught ReferenceError: okButtonElementFirebase is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function okButtonELementFirebase(){
```

You have a typo - okButtonE**L**ementFirebase should be okButtonE**l**ementFirebase.

Comment: OMG. been debugging for a while. thanks nkostic. God bless you :)

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept this as an answer.